# Is it safe to assign sensitive input value to a Jquery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it safe to assign sensitive input value to a Jquery variable?
For example,

```
var creditcardnum = $("input#cardNumber").val();
//do some things
$("input#abc").val(creditcardnum);
```

I am not sending any sensitive data to the server and I am only assigning the sensitive values to Jquery variables for the above code. (i.e. I do not call the variable on any other pages) I do use SSL, but I wasn't sure if this was safe practice.

Comment: yes, that's fine. if you have CC# already displayed somewhere on page (or within a hidden field or something) then setting another variable value with CC Number does not really make any difference.

Comment: Of course it is. You're obviously not asking for credit card information without SSL and a secure server, and just copying the value from one element to another on the clientside has no effect on the security of your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery to set the value of an input does not add any security hole. The value is not set to the jQuery object. It is set to the input, using jquery methods.

Any other script could watch this input value with or wihout jQuery. You may also have val filters you can add to jQuery.valHooks.input object, to listen to jQuery val method uses on inputs.

Other scripts you would add to this page from any commercial widget without iframes have to be trusted.

The danger resides in sending data to server but you use SSL.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just client side manipulation you're doing with the jQuery, and you do say you're not sending any data to the server, then this should be safe. The risk comes when data is sent between client and server.

You might want to be sure that you destroy any objects you create, so when you're finished using that `creditcardnum` variable explicitly set it to null, but if you're scoping your variables they'll automatically get released when your functions are done. Take a look at the [Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) which shows an approach for keeping your variables scoped well

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I chose the other answer because it was easier to understand for a noob like me :(